# Creating table script with values in codebehind inC#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to build a console application with ado.net where I get a table from the database and convert it to a string output in a file. I want to do this with stringbuilder. But before I fetch the data and write it to the string builder I want to fill 2 fields of the table Person "name" and "last name" with "xxx". End result must be a file with create and insert values statement in tsql.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ConString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True";

           

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            string querystring = "Select * from person";

           

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querystring, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString() + reader[3].ToString());
            }

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("");
            //CREATE TABLE Person
            //[name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
            //[surname] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,        
            //[Gender] [varchar](5) NOT NULL


            //INSERT VALUES (...,...) with modifyed name and surname data and put it in the stringbuilder


            string innerString = builder.ToString();

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\script.txt"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(innerString.ToString());
            }

         
               
            Console.Read();
        }

       
    }
```

Is there a smart way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this is what you're after:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ConString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Clients;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        string querystring = "Select * from person";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querystring, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine("CREATE TABLE PERSON");
        builder.AppendLine("(");
        builder.AppendLine("[name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,");
        builder.AppendLine("[surname] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,");
        builder.AppendLine("[gender] [varchar](5) NOT NULL");
        builder.AppendLine(")");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var name = reader[0].ToString();
            var surname = reader[1].ToString();
            var gender = reader[2].ToString();
            var value4 = reader[3].ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(name + " " + surname + " " + gender + value4);

            builder.AppendLine("INSERT INTO PERSON (name, surname, gender) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + gender + "')");
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\script.txt", builder.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. i need to get the table names from sql so that it becomes generic. This solution provides hard coded strings. And the gender column must be filled with the data in the table in sql.